# Why does alert(["a","b","c","d","e"][[1,2],3,4]) output e in javascript?

Tags: javascript, alert

Could someone tell me why:

```
alert(["a","b","c","d","e"][[1,2],3,4])
```

outputs e in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because comma is an operator that executes all of the separated instructions ([in fact](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator): two instructions, each of which can also use a comma operator) and returns the results of the last one. I.e.:

```
["a","b","c","d","e"][[1,2],3,4] => ["a","b","c","d","e"][4] === "e"
```